# Triger excel solver using command button in visual basic

Tags: excel, vba, vb6

I want to trigger an Excel macro [i.e. Excel Solver] using visual basic 6.

Comment: @Jean Wrong site. Go to http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

**How To Create and Call an Excel Macro Programmatically from VB**

 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194611

See Also:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/219151